# how to print record type attributes of a variable using FND_FILE.PUT_LINE - Oracle

Tags: sql, plsql, oracle-ebs

A PLSQL program uses a variable named x_api_errors, which is a record type defined as:
[image]

I want to print x_api_errors.message_name and x_api_errors.message_text to Oracle EBS job log using FND_FILE.PUT_LINE.

I expected this could easliy be done using (according to documentation this should work):

```
FND_FILE.PUT_LINE(FND_FILE.LOG,v_api_errors.message_name);
```

..but it is giving:

```
[Error] PLS-00306 (343: 21): 
PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'PUT_LINE'
```

How can I make this work?  It seems to be a problem related to type conversion because when I try to do:

```
v_errorMessage:=v_api_errors.message_name;
```

It gives error:

```
[Error] PLS-00382 (344: 50): 
PLS-00382: expression is of wrong type
```

..but I am not able to `TO_CHAR` or `CAST` v_api_errors.message_name to VARCHAR2.

Comment: Can not test hence comment not Answer but have a look at https://itz4oracleapps.blogspot.com/2012/03/update-po-line-price-oracle-apps.html.  They declare l_api_errors po_api_errors_rec_type; then access via a loop
 FOR i IN 1 .. l_api_errors.message_text.COUNT
LOOP
  put_log (l_api_errors.message_text (i));
END LOOP;

Comment: This suggests that potentially you need to be doing v_api_errors.message_name(1)....

Comment: You can move that to an answer.  It is a working solution.  Thank you.

Comment: done glad it worked for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per the article at https://itz4oracleapps.blogspot.com/2012/03/update-po-line-price-oracle-apps.html

In there example they delcare

```
 l_api_errors po_api_errors_rec_type;
```

Then when they access it they access it they use a loop as below

```
FOR i IN 1 .. l_api_errors.message_text.COUNT LOOP
  put_log (l_api_errors.message_text (i)); 
END LOOP;
```

This indicates that the 'Nested objects' as seen in your screenshot are arrays and will need to be accessed using the array syntax eg

```
v_api_errors.message_name(1)
```